# Contemporary objections to the Bill of Rights's 1st Amendment / Declaration of the Rights of Man, art. 10?

Tags: united-states, religion, france, constitution

What were the objections to the Bill of Rights's 1st Amendment when it was first published?

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or
>   prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of
>   speech, or of the press, or the right of the people peaceably to
>   assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.

(ratified: 15 Dec. 1791)

and/or France's *Déclaration des droits de l'homme et du citoyen*, article 10:

> *Nul ne doit être inquiété pour ses opinions, même religieuses, pourvu que leur manifestation ne trouble pas l'ordre public établi par
>   la Loi.* [No one shall be disquieted on account of his opinions,
>   including his religious views, provided their manifestation does not
>   disturb the public order established by law.]

(26 Aug. 1789)

?

Comment: Which specific aspect of the 1st Amendment?

Comment: @DVK: Freedom of religion and speech, specifically, because they're linked. The 1st Amendment essentially says that true and false religions have equal footing, as do truths and lies in public speech.

Comment: Please narrow the timeframe. Are you interested in 1789-1799? Or maybe 1964-1974?

Comment: @kubanczyk: 18th century. I've edited the title etc. to reflect this.

Comment: Perhaps "Contemporary objections"?

Comment: There were political objections to the Bill of Rights in general from the Federalists in the Constitutional Convention. They believed the BoR compromised certain powers of the Federal Government that were necessary for national defense. They promised to ratify the BoR, subsequent to ratification of the body of the Constitution, as a compromise, to garner the votes necessary for ratification. But what reason do you have to believe there was some objection to Amendment I particular? Far more provocative were Amendments IX and X. Your question needs to be sourced. Until then, I vote to close.

Comment: _The 1st Amendment essentially says that true and false religions have equal footing_ : **No:** Amendment I has **nothing to say** about the truth or non-truth of **any** religion. It simply says Congress has no power to legislate on the subject. Same with speech and the press.

Comment: @Vector: No one argued like that in objecting to the 1st Amendment? This is what I'd like to know.

Comment: I voted to close: You should not ask a question here based on your own speculation and personal beliefs. If you have contemporary sources substantiating such objections, bring them and ask a question if you don't find them satisfactory. Your question is it stands is idle speculation, not History. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) : _there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do"_

Comment: @Geremia - _No one argued like that in objecting to the 1st Amendment_ -Why should someone argue like that? Do you believe there were those who believed the USA should be some sort of theocracy? I believe you'd be hard pressed to find such a position. The Constitution makes no mention of a God or a particular Religion-it's a decidely **secular** document. To be **Just**, it **had** to be that way. It's one of the founding principles of the USA-the USA was built by people who fled from the theocracies of Europe. If you have evidence to the contrary, **bring it,** or this is an invalid question.

Comment: @Geremia there are no "true" and "false" religions, unless you're religious and believe all other religions are "false religions". That's what the establishment clause is designed to protect against, one religion causing all others to be banned.

Comment: @Vector: Not only like I do, but also not like I do. There _has_ to be people who objected to the 1st Amendment or the Declaration of the Rights of Man art. 10. That is what my question is asking. Just because you may not agree with what I've written in the comments here doesn't mean my question is invalid.